# May you give any recommend to me for using animation slide down and up in Angular 4.*?

Tags: angular, animation

I am first start using Angular 4. I want to make animation slide down and up in Angular 4. If you can, I want the code

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: []
  ...
})
```

Thanks so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's working. Self Answer

```
 animations: [
    trigger('moreOption', [
      state('inactive', style({
        padding: '0 30px 0 30px',
        height: '0px',      
        overflow: 'hidden'
      })),
      state('active', style({
        padding: '25px 30px 60px 30px',
        height: 'auto',
        overflow: 'hidden'    
      })),
      transition('inactive <=> active', animate('400ms'))
    ]
```